# how to make select tag show options by default without clicking

Tags: jquery

I had created a dropdown using `<select>` tag and now i want to show the options in `<select>` without clicking the dropdown(i mean when we open that html, we should be able to see all options instead of clicking on the select ). Is this possible using jQuery or is there any other way to do it.

Below is my code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/xtTcZ/

I want the options to be shown like below by default

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

normally you would just set the `size` property on the `select` but it doesn't like like jquery mobile supports that. no mention in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html) at least.

ex:

```
<select size="4">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. In jQuery Mobile if we put size, it's showing the list as blank. I need to think of some thing else. Anyways, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The select element has the attribute `size` which specifies how many rows should be visible.

```
<select size="3">
    <option>Row 1</option>
    <option>Row 2</option>
    <option>Row 3</option>
</select>
```